# Error integrating Grafana to Okta with https protocol

Tags: grafana, openid-connect, openid, okta, okta-api

I am trying to integrate OSS edition of Grafana to Okta OIDC using the following guide - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/okta/

I am running a grafana locally using docker, URL: https://localhost/login

Okta integration is working perfectly fine when I am running it with non https, eg: if I run the application with http://localhost:3000/login the okta integration works fine same with https it does not work.

Any leads to fix this issue?

Comment: The error is: "Your request resulted in an error. The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be a Login redirect URI in the client app settings: https://-******admin.okta.com/admin/app/oidc_client/instance/*******#tab-general"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue with setting the rool_url